# How to set x button unclickable when show confirmation dialog?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

when I click x button app show confirmation dialog and if I click x button 2nd time, error occur because app can not create 2 dialogs at same time. 
 Currently I can ignore 2nd x button click event by using a variable `isBtnCloseClicked`to save state of x and only create dialog when `isBtnCloseClicked=false`. But I don't want to register the state variable in every windows. Is there other way to do this using default UWP API ?, for example: disable x button when the dialog shows up.
 
Below is my code to handle x button event.

```
 Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested +=
            async (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.Handled = true;
                    ContentDialog locationPromptDialog = new ContentDialog
                    {
                        Title = "Do you want to exit?",
                        Content = "",
                        CloseButtonText = "No",
                        PrimaryButtonText = "Yes"
                    };
                    ContentDialogResult result = await locationPromptDialog.ShowAsync();
                    args.Handled = false;
                    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
                    {
                        App.Current.Exit();
                    }              
            };
```

Error when click x button 2nd time

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  Message=An async operation was not properly started.

Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time.
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog.ShowAsync()
   at CORsvr.MainPage.
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you tried and where the error is occurring? This is how none can help you.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: You can't use async void on a event where you do things like `args.Handled = something`, the event will finish and it will use the initial value of Handled not the value you set in your function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested +=
            async (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.Handled = true;

                var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Do you want to exit?");


                messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
                    "OK", 
                    new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.OKCommandInvokedHandler)));
                messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
                    "Cancel", 
                    new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CancelCommandInvokedHandler)));


                messageDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
                messageDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            };

private void OKCommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{

}

private void CancelCommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code work fine! However I still don't understand what different between ContentDialog and MessageDialog here and is it possible to do same behaviour with ContentDialog. Could you explain a bit?.

Comment: You are welcome. There is no major difference in CD and MD. But you can add some content in CD while MD has its own fixed format for showing up caption and message with buttons. If you want to see in detail example. Please check https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-10-xaml-tips-messagedialog-and-contentdialog    ......................... Please mark as a answer if it helped you and other persons can use it.